# how to render multiple antd tables?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need to render multiple tables instead of one table with many columns.

Currently the table looks like,
[image]

which renders data into multiple columns.
I need the data to be rendered into two different tables like,

[image]

The code crashes for some reason while trying to render two tables.

Code:

```
function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      key: "1",
      rollNo: "16CS21",
      name: "Ronald",
      rank: 2
    },
    {
      key: "2",
      rollNo: "16CS72",
      name: "John",
      rank: 4
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((d) => (
        <DetailComponent data={d} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Table rendering Component:

```
function DetailComponent({ data }) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Table
            dataSource={data}
            pagination={false}
            bordered={false}
            style={{ height: "0px" }}
          >
            <Column title="Roll No" dataIndex="rollNo" key="rollNo" width="100px" />
            <Column title="Name" dataIndex="name" key="name" />
            <Column title="rank" key="rank" dataIndex="rank" />
            <Column
              title="Action"
              key="action"
              render={() => (
                <Space size="middle">
                  <EditTwoTone style={{ fontSize: "18px" }} />
                  <DeleteTwoTone style={{ fontSize: "18px" }} twoToneColor="red" />
                </Space>
              )}
            />
          </Table>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

CodeSanbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/tree-data-antd-4-21-0-forked-xxhks9?file=/demo.js

Comment: could you paste error?

Comment: also sandbox is not working

Comment: Yes, sandbox also crashes. Error :  `rawData.some is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see two issues.

1. unique key prop issue.
2. remove round brackets like so in map function.

> data.map((d)=>dataComponent)

**Edit:**

It seems to me that your table component takes list of objects as data input while you're passing single object. try converting object to array of obejcts like so:

> [].concat(d)

**edit**

Solution mentioned above seems to fix the issue
as shown:

[image]

Right now both tables are overlaping on each other. which you can fix.

Comment: Passed in key to table and also tried removing round brackets. You can check the code sandbox

Comment: i dint understand. Mine is already a array of object. Can you edit the code in codesandbox